# Migrate LV with 1 mirror to 2 new disks (also mirrored)

Tags: redhat, lvm, mirror

I have one LV that is mirrored on 2 PV :

- /dev/mapper/mpatha
- /dev/mapper/mpathb

There is a 4mb LV on /dev/mapper/mpatha that holds the mirror log.

I am trying to migrate this LV on 2 new devices, with one of them holding the tiny log LV.

- /dev/mapper/mpaths
- /dev/mapper/mpatht

(sizes are identical between old and new devices)

Here is what I did so far :

```
pvcreate /dev/mapper/mpaths
pvcreate /dev/mapper/mpatht
vgextend vgdb2i1hom /dev/mapper/mpaths /dev/mapper/mpatht
lvconvert -m3 vgdb2i1hom/lvmnt0 /dev/mapper/mpaths /dev/mapper/mpatht
```

At this point I have 4 mirrors as expected.
Now trying to remove one mirror holding the log LV :

```
lvconvert -m2 vgdb2i1hom/lvmnt0 /dev/mapper/mpatha
```

Mirror from mpatha was removed but log LV is still here

```
# lvs -a -o +devices vgdb2i1hom
LV                VG         Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log           Cpy%Sync Convert Devices
lvmnt0            vgdb2i1hom mwi-aom--- 49.99g                                [lvmnt0_mlog] 100.00           lvmnt0_mimage_2(0),lvmnt0_mimage_3(0),lvmnt0_mimage_4(0)
[lvmnt0_mimage_4] vgdb2i1hom iwi-aom--- 49.99g                                                               /dev/mapper/mpaths(0)
[lvmnt0_mimage_3] vgdb2i1hom iwi-aom--- 49.99g                                                               /dev/mapper/mpatht(0)
[lvmnt0_mimage_2] vgdb2i1hom iwi-aom--- 49.99g                                                               /dev/mapper/mpathb(0)
[lvmnt0_mlog]     vgdb2i1hom lwi-aom---  4.00m                                                               /dev/mapper/mpatha(2559)
```

How do I migrate this LV to new disk ?

Also :

```
[root@lblusd4t ~]# lvm version
  LVM version:     2.02.143(2)-RHEL6 (2016-12-13)
  Library version: 1.02.117-RHEL6 (2016-12-13)
  Driver version:  4.33.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lvconvert --mirrorlog core vgdb2i1hom/lvmnt0
lvconvert --mirrorlog disk vgdb2i1hom/lvmnt0
```

fixed everything

log LV is now on new device